# Ram Shyam throws a dice one after another. One who throws a higher number wins. Ram throws and gets 3. What is the probability that Shyam wins?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Ram Shyam throws a dice one after another. One who throws a higher number wins. Ram throws and gets 3. What is the probability that Shyam wins?

> Here in this question:
>   Ram is said to have got 3, so for Shyam to win either he has to get 4 or 5 or 6 to beat Ram..thus his probability to do that would be $\frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{2}$
>   Also if we consider the case that Shyam gets the same number as of Ram i.e 3, so for Shyam to get 3 his probabilty would be $=\frac{1}{6}$
>   Thus considering all the cases I would have total probabilty summed up to $=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6} = \frac{2}{3}$
>   (Am I doing something wrong...plz suggest )
>   I actually don't have the final answer with me given in my text book so I request to please comment about my approach whether it's right or lacking something or not...and if yes then please do tell what's the correct answer..??

Comment: Does $S$ win if there is a tie?   That really should be stated.  I'd have thought they simply toss again.

Comment: Nothing about tie is actually stated in the problem..but I just considered it...

Comment: Then in that case are you talking about something like this: 1/2+(1/6)^1.(1/2)+(1/6)^2.(1/2)+...

Comment: Well, whatever assumption you want to make should be stated explicitly.  Your calculation assumes $S$ wins all ties.  With that assumption, you are correct.  More simply, with that assumption $S$ needs a $3,4,5,6$ to win.   More interesting to solve the problem with the assumption that ties restart the game.

Comment: I don't understand your second comment.  there's no need for infinite series in this.  Before any toss, each player has a $\frac 12$ chance of winning (by symmetry).  Given that $R$ tosses a $3$, $S$ has two ways to win.  Either $S$ throws a $4,5,6$ or $S$ throws a $3$ and wins after the game restarts.  Thus $p_S=\frac 12+\frac 16\times \frac 12$.

Comment: Actually in that infinite series cases would be like (S wins) or (S gets a tie)*(In second trial of game S wins) or (S gets a tie)*(S gets a tie)*(third trial S wins)... I did this infinite sum so that they restart the game on getting a tie...which you suggested...(is that right way I calculated..)??

Comment: If there is a restart after ties then we are dealing with a fair game and the probability that Shyam wins is $\frac12+\frac16\frac12$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Shyam throws $4$, $5$ or $6$, he wins; the probability of throwing $4$, $5$ or $6$ is $3/6=1/2$

If Shyam throws $3$, the game restarts; he probability of throwing $3$ is $1/6$

If the game restarts, Shyam wins with probability $1/2$

The total probability of winning is
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: But what if when the game restarts and Shyam again gets 3..so wouldn't that be something like an infinite series...??

Comment: Like something of this sort: (1/2)+(1/6)^1.(1/2)+(1/6)^2.(1/2)+... infinite times

Comment: @PeterSmith The game continues until somebody wins and the game is fair; so probability of winning is $1/2$ for each player.

Comment: Okay I got it thanks